# New to Java, Method X in class y cannot be applied

Tags: java

I'm new to java and was looking for some advice. I was assigned the problem below and I cannot get the compare method to run for the life of me. It won't compile. I receive the following error:

```
error: method compare in class Plateau cannot be applied to given types;                                                                                           
        compare(a[N]); 
required: int[],int                                                                                                                                                                     
  found: int                                                                                                                                                                              
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

1.4.21 Longest plateau. Given an array of integers, find the length and location of the longest contiguous sequence of equal values where the values of the elements just before and just after this sequence are smaller. The array should be passed to a method and the results should be printed to the screen.

```
public class Plateau{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    int N = args.length;
    int[] a = new int [N];

        for (int i=0; i < N; i++){
            int number = Integer.parseInt(args[i]);
            a[i]=number;
        }
        compare(a[N]);
    }

    public static void compare(int[] a, int N){
    int comp = a[0];
    int current_length=0;
    int max=0;
    int maxlength=0;

        for(int l=0; l < N; l++){
        if (a[l] > comp){
        current_length = 0;
        comp = a[l];
        max = a[l];
        }

        if (a[l] == comp){
            current_length+=1;
            comp = a[l];
        }
        else if (a[l] < comp && a[l] < max){
        comp = a[l-1];
        current_length=maxlength;
            l++;
        }
        }

        System.out.println(max);
        System.out.println(maxlength);
    }
}
```

Comment: Try `compare(a,N);`

Comment: `compare(int[] a, int N)` takes 2 params but is called with 1 argument `compare(a[N])` . start with any book for beginners (language does not matter)

Answer (score 2):

It is quite obvious: the arguments expects an array and a value (length? index), but you are just passing one value from the array.

Just turn

```
compare(a[N]);
```

to

```
compare(a, N);
```

Comment: thanks! I didn't realize once i declared a[] that i can reference it as simple a

Answer (score 2):

The problem is an issue with parameters and method signature. As I can see that you are learning, I will not give you a full solution. I will only point you to a way to solve it

1. The method `compare` expects two parameters `int[] a, int N`, but you are only calling it with one `compare(a[N])`
2. `a[N]` is wrong, because it would index an element outside of the array (mind that array index goes from 0 to N-1)
3. `a` is the array of type int[], so you need to use this as the first parameter of the call to `compare`
4. `N` is the number of elements (of type int) in the array, so this could be the second parameter

Answer (score 0):

Your method signature doesn't match the way you are trying to invoke it.  In your main method, you are trying to call a method called compare that takes an array of integers, but the only definition you have is for a compare method that takes both an array of integers and a single integer.  The usage and definition need to be consistent, or the compiler won't know what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Your method

```
  public static void compare(int[] a, int N){
```

takes two parameters one is integer array and other is a integer

When you call that method in your main method you are passing only one parameter

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    int N = args.length;
    int[] a = new int [N]; 

        for (int i=0; i < N; i++){
        int number = Integer.parseInt(args[i]);
        a[i]=number;}
    compare(a,N); // pass a integer along with your integer array (you have to use your array variable which is a and not a[N])
    }
```

and thats why you are getting that error pass an integer along with that and it will work
Also you are passing the array incorrectly

```
int[] a = new int [N];
```

you have declared array here and thus you need to pass the variable a and not a[N]